# Flutter Web Firebase handle background message

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

Is it possible to receive background notifications in flutter web. By following the official documentation, I have managed to receive the background notifications is a serviceworker javascript file. But I am stuck, on how to relay that notification from javascript to dart code?. Tried many samples using js interop etc. But service worker js won't recognise any functions that I wrapped in dart code. Any help?.

My question is I receive background notification in service worker js onBackgroundMessage event, but not sure how to relay that to dart code.

Comment: I am trying for the same, I want notification data on click of Notification , but I didn't found any way, my service worker does even execute console.log()...